# Android AWS SDK : Cognito Identity not was not found in region metadata

Tags: android, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am writing a simple test app to connect to AWS using android APP. I am providing identity pool credentials through the CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider Constructor. On the AWS console, I have created an Identity Pool and I have checked "Enable access to Unauthenticated identities". A corresponding IAM role is created with basic access to AWS services.

However, when I run my android code, I am always getting the error: "{cognito-identity, us-west-2} was not found in region metadata, trying to construct an endpoint using the standard pattern for this region: 'cognito-identity.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'.

I have followed all the instructions given in aws docs. I am not able understand where I am going wrong. If any one has experienced this or knows a solution for what I am doing wrong, I will appreciate the help very much.

The android code for CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider constructor is copied from SourceCode section of Identity Pool Console of AWS. The android code I have written is as follows:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fhButton);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showClick();
        }
    });

}

public void showClick(){
    Log.i("TEST", "Hurray!");

    new AsyncTask(){
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
            CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXX", // Identity Pool ID
                    Regions.US_WEST_2 // Region
            );
            Log.i("TEST",credentialsProvider.getIdentityId());

            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you see the identity ID on logcat? From this post on the AWS forums, it might just be that the message is misleading: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=579411

Comment: I've added it as an answer, so it might help others in need. Feel free to accept if you think it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see the identity ID on logcat? From [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=579411) on the AWS forums, it might just be that the message is misleading, but the call actually works.

Comment: Hi @Viccari, I did came across the post too. Ignored the message and went ahead with writing code to use AWS services and it worked. It is a misleading message. Marking the answer as accepted as this will help others